# How to create clustered index in Typeorm

Tags: typeorm

Google doesn't have an answer to this question.
The documentation does not answer this question.
For postgresql, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a clustered index is more of an administrative task.
Therefore, it is not provided in the typeorm to specify a clustered index in the database.
As a developer, you must provide for routine maintenance of the database.
Also create guidelines for creating clustered indexes for tables.
I'm going to make a script like this:
CLUSTER table_name USING index_name
...
and add a scheduler when deploying the application.